# Palindromic prime

Tags: code-golf, tips, primes, python, palindrome

I'm solving task, where:

### Input:

A number as an integer.

### Output:

The closest greater palindromic prime as an integer.

I would appreciate *hints* how to make my solution shorter. Or directions if change of approach would be beneficial.

```
golf=lambda l,r=range:next(x for x in r(10**6)if(x==int(`x`[::-1]))&all(x%d for d in r(2,x))and x>l)
```

palindromic:

```
x==int(`x`[::-1])
```

prime:

```
all(x%d for d in r(2,x))
```

Comment: Before people close vote this, because it's not a challenge: [things like this are on-topic now](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1724/8478). The only thing I'm wondering is if this wasn't better suited as two separate questions "How can I make checking for palindromic numbers shorter?" and "How can I make checking for primes shorter?" (@Martin, don't do that though, until you get more feedback confirming this.)

Comment: @m.buettner, ok thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now, for some really big improvements. Your original program was 97 characters:

```
n=lambda l,r=range:next(x for x in r(10**6)if(x==int(`x`[::-1]))&all(x%d for d in r(2,x))and x>l)
```

With the improvements below, you could get to 90 characters:

```
n=lambda l,r=range:min(x for x in r(l+1,10**6)if(`x`==`x`[::-1])&all(x%d for d in r(2,x)))
```

With a trick to eliminate the parentheses around the palindrome checking statement, you can get to 87:

```
n=lambda l,r=range:min(x for x in r(l+1,10**4)if`x`==`x`[::-1]*all(x%d for d in r(2,x)))
```

However, I have a solution in 80 characters. To get it, focus on changing the big picture, not the individual components. Rethink your most basic choices in getting to this point. Why a lambda? Why a min of a filtered range? There may be a better way.

---

Using `int()` in the palindrome comparison is a lot of characters - can you see a shorter way to turn

```
x
```

and

```
`x`[::-1]
```

into the same type?

Also, that `and x>l` bit at the end is a lot of characters. Is there a way we could shorten it? Eliminate the need for it by changing something else?

Is `next` the right function for the job? Remember, this is code golf, runtime is irrelevant.

The prime checking function looks spot on, though.

Also, and this is merely aesthetic, I don't like aliasing functions, the way you are doing with range, when it doesn't save any characters, as in this case.

Comment: int for `x`==`x`[::-1], next for index [0] ...still thinking about and x>l

Comment: @MartinRajnoha HINT: take a deeper look into the `range` function.

Comment: Thx, guys I found that :) Current status -10chars. Great!

Comment: @MartinRajnoha As a quick reference point, I was able (in my short time golfing down your code) to remove 12 characters.

Comment: @BeetDemGuise now you are teasing me :) OK, how did u manage that?

Comment: @MartinRajnoha I have a solution with 17 less characters. See edited answer for hints.

Comment: @MartinRajnoha `\`` is your friend.